# Smalltalk Visual Works concurrency

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, smalltalk, visualworks

With the follwing code, I expect an output like

```
AA
BB
AA
AA
AA
BB
```

Code:

```
p1 := [ 1 to: 3000 do: [:i | Transcript show: 'AA';cr.] ] newProcess.
p2 := [ 5000 to: 8100 do: [:i | Transcript show: 'BB';cr.] ] newProcess. 
p1 resume.
p2 resume.
```

But it first prints all the AAs and then  all the BBs. 
Works fine under Pharo, but not VisualWorks. Can someone tell the bug?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a "bug." What I see are two processes with the same priority, one queued after the other. What makes you think that each of the processes should yield and let the other run in a non-preemptive environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualWorks uses non-preemptive multitasking  This means that when two processes have the same priority, one process needs to yield in order to another to run.  Try running the following code to see the difference:

```
p1 := [ 1 to: 3000 do: [:i |
    Transcript show: 'AA';cr.
    i \\ 10 = 0 ifTrue: [Processor activeProcess yield]] ] newProcess.
p2 := [ 5001 to: 8101 do: [:i |
    Transcript show: 'BB';cr.
    i \\ 10 = 0 ifTrue: [Processor activeProcess yield]] ] newProcess. 
p1 resume.
p2 resume.
```

Comment: Pharo behaves differently; is it because it is preemptive?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia no, Squeak/Pharo have non preemptive scheduling too. It must come from some Morphic interaction (I can't tell exactly where/when though) - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer of David Buck is perfect: the process scheduler is not preemptive, so two processes of same priority will run sequentially rather than concurrently, unless the active one will wait for a non ready Semaphore or explicitely yield.

But Pharo and Squeak use same non preemptive scheduling, so why the difference?
It comes from Morphic interaction, it's very difficult to guess exactly where/when, I'm not a Morphic expert...
But if you use a SharedQueue rather than Transcript, you'll get same behavior as Visualworks, all 'AA' then all 'BB':

```
q := SharedQueue new: 6101.
s1 := Semaphore new.
s2 := Semaphore new.
p1 := [ 1 to: 3000 do: [:i | q nextPut: 'AA']. s1 signal ] newProcess.
p2 := [ 5000 to: 8100 do: [:i | q nextPut: 'BB'.]. s2 signal ] newProcess. 
p1 resume.
p2 resume.
s1 wait.
s2 wait.
q inspect.
```